# ¿Libros similares a "Lecciones de Lengua Castellana"?

Tags: recursos

En casa de mis padres me reencontré el otro día una copia bastante vieja ya del libro Lecciones de lengua castellana (Edición americana) - Curso superior, por Colecciones G. M. Bruño.

Es un libro que me parece muy interesante porque no es simplemente un listado de reglas gramaticales y explicaciones, sino que contiene además una sección que habla sobre la historia del español, tiene muchas explicaciones etimológicas de vocabulario y tiene varios extractos de poemas, cuentos u otros escritos para acompañar las explicaciones.

La copia de la que hablo es una edición de 1964, de la editorial Bedout en Colombia. Creo que ya el libro se encuentra discontinuado porque lo que he encontrado en internet son igual ediciones viejas.

Me gustaría saber si conocen un libro actual que sea al menos similar a este libro. Es decir, uno que no sea exclusivamente gramática sino que conserve ese espíritu "integral" de este libro.

Aclaraciones:

- Con libro "actual" me refiero a algo publicado aunque sea alrededor del 2000. Claro, si hay algo reciente, mucho mejor.
- Busco un libro en papel, no digital.

[image]

Comment: Se puede ver en una biblioteca.

Comment: Biblioteca nacional de España: https://www.bne.es/es/catalogos/biblioteca-digital-hispanica

Comment: @Lambie el pibe es colombiano y vos lo mandás a una bliblioteca que está en España??

Comment: Gracias @Lambie. Sin embargo, mi pregunta se refiere a si conocen libros un poco más actuales pero similares a éste. Aclararé también en la pregunta que sea libro físico.

Comment: @tac Claro, porque una biblioteca tambien funciona como una bibliografia.

Comment: digitalizados: http://bdh.bne.es/bnesearch/Search.do?sort=&numfields=3&advanced=true&field3Op=AND&field2Op=AND&field1Op=AND&textH=&completeText=on&fechaHsearchtype=1&lengua=Espa%C3%B1ol&field1=todos&field3val=&showYearItems=&field1val=&field2val=&fechaHhasta=&fechaHen=&exact=on&text=gramatica&field3=todos&fechaHdesde=&field2=todos&doctype=Libro&pageNumber=1&pageSize=30&language=&accesotematico1=LING%C3%9C%C3%8DSTICA.+LITERATURA&accesotematico2=Ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica+y+lenguas&fechaFdesde=1900&fechaFhasta=2023 Por ejemplo: Ejercicios de gramática castellana / dispuestos por Narciso Alonso Cortés

Comment: Se buscas los títulos en qualquier bibliografia y después se puede comprar...